# How handles JPA JOINs with available foreign key entry but not available foreign entry?

Tags: java, jpa, join, null, foreign-key-relationship

I wonder how JPA defines to handle following scenario:

```
Table A: | Table B:
ID  FK_B | ID
1   10   | 10
2   null | 12
3   11   |
```

I want all Table A entries with FK_B NULL or referencing not available Table B entry.

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_B", nullable = true)
    @ManyToOne
    private B b;
}

public class B implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

Is it defined, what happens if I use

```
SELECT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN a.b WHERE a.b IS NULL
```

or: (Is this possible?)

```
SELECT a FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b on (b = a.b) WHERE b IS NULL
```

What I need is a list containing

```
A(id = 2)
A(id = 3)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row #3 in your Table A is illegal by definition; if there's no `B` with ID=11 you can't have that row in table `A` for you'd be violating the foreign key constraint.

As far as getting all rows from `A` where `B` is null, your first query should work. You can also try:

```
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.b.id IS NULL
```

although I'm not 100% sure whether that's valid JPA QL syntax (it works for Hibernate)

Comment: I must learn, that this statemant only works with hibernate, but not with toplink ;-)

For your statement toplink generate this SQL statement:

SELECT t0.ID, t0.FK_B FROM A t0, B t1 WHERE (t1.ID IS NULL) AND (t1.ID = t0.FK_B)

THis works fine with both hibernate and toplink:

SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.b IS NULL

Than toplink build this statement:

SELECT t0.ID, t0.FK_B FROM A t0 WHERE (t0.FK_B IS NULL)